# Java consumers ability to accept and return boolean or string

Tags: java, lambda, syntax, interface

This is a regular Consumer with usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Consumer<String> consumer = (str) -> {
        //stuff
    };

    consumer.accept(args[0]);
}
```

Here is what I am attempting to do (make it so consumer returns as boolean)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Consumer<String> consumer = (str) -> {
        return str.equals("yes"); //type mis-match error because consumer is void not boolean
    };

    boolean a = consumer.accept(args[0]); //type mis-match error because consumer is void not boolean
}
```

How can I manipulate consumer to return as a boolean?

Without obviously creating a whole new interface.... (below)

```
public interface ConsumerB {
    boolean accept(String s);
}
```

Comment: A Consumer, by definition, doesn't return anything. A functional interface that returns a boolean is called a Predicate. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html

Comment: Did not know that, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

For the case in which one wants to pass a `String` and get a `boolean`, one can use [`Predicate<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html). There are similiar functions if one wants to return one of the following primitives:

- for `int`: [`ToIntFunction<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html),
- for `long`: [`ToLongFunction<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/ToLongFunction.html), and
- for `double`: [`ToDoubleFunction<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/ToDoubleFunction.html).

In line with the [rest of the `java.util.function`-](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) and the [`java.util.stream` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), there are no further `To<Primitive>Function` interfaces for the primitives `byte`, `short`, `char` and `float`.

For the case in which one wants to pass a `String` and get a `String`, one can use [`UnaryOperator<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html).

For the general case in which one wants to pass some `T` and get some `R`, one can use [`Function<T, R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html).

Whether this, however, improves the readability of the code is another question...

Answer (score 10):

A consumer that returns something is not a consumer anymore. It becomes a [`Predicate<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html):

```
Predicate<String> consumer = (str) -> {
    return str.equals("yes"); 
};
```

You also mentioned in the title that you want the functional interface to return a `String`. In that case, use [`Function<String, String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html).

Comment: The `Predicate` is limited to `boolean` as returnt type. The general case is `Function<T, R>`.

Comment: @Turing85 I am aware of that. But from the question, the OP wants a functional interface that returns a primitive `boolean`. You can't put the primitive `boolean` type into `Function<String, boolean>`, can you?

Comment: You could use `Function<String, Boolean>`, but since `Predicate` exists, it is superfluous. =)